# Is it possible to alter existing data with Django's fixtures?

Tags: python, django, json, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm using Django's fixtures in my tests. I need to create UserProfile fixture. The first problem is that it's pointed to User entry. To deal with it, I'm using natural keys. So I just say that UserProfile fixture's user field is User fixture's actual username.

```
[
    {
        "pk": 8002,
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields": {
            "date_joined": "2012-08-28 10:00:00.000000+00:00",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "groups": [],
            "is_active": true,
            "is_staff": false,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "last_login": "2012-08-28 10:00:00.000000+00:00",
            "last_name": "",
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$ltmEKsdCPjuK$74ZwNUh8rqFAPZ6+Cmi3tc8A94ueeXTplFqOQKlY4hc=",
            "user_permissions": [],
            "username": "user8002"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": null,
        "model": "spam_and_eggs.userprofile",
        "fields": {
            "user": ["user8002"],
            "language": "",
            "email_activated": true
        }
     }
]
```

Unfortunately, it gives back an error:

```
IntegrityError: Could not load share4you.UserProfile(pk=None): column user_id is not unique
```

Here comes the second problem. I think that it may fail because UserProfile is automatically created when user is created using Django's signals and fixture fails because UserProfile for that User is already created. Can it be the reason? Are there any ways to fix it?

Thanks in any advice!

**Edit #1:**

Model and signal:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email_activated = models.BooleanField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

User models is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Comment: Can you post your models and signal receivers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to alter existing data with Django's fixtures?

Absolutely, if a fixture has a pk which exists in the database, django will do an update.

> user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

That is rather interesting, why not a OneToOneField in that case ?

```
>>> a=User.objects.all()[0]

>>> a.userprofile_set.all()
[<UserProfile: UserProfile object>]

>> a.userprofile_set.create(language='bar')
IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique
```

> IntegrityError: Could not load share4you.UserProfile(pk=None): column user_id is not unique

- Instead of `pk=null`, set a real integer
- Instead of `"user": ["user8002"]`, you should set `"user": 8002`.

> I think that it may fail because UserProfile is automatically created when user is created using Django's signals and fixture fails because UserProfile for that User is already created.

I could not reproduce this behavior. These fixtures can load and reload just fine with your models:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields": {
            "username": "jpic",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "is_active": true,
            "is_superuser": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "last_login": "2012-06-11T06:44:57.637Z",
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": [],
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$KzsUTACvZgJU$qvywXdVv/N3s5lifS/gQxSGog36ExGbuj2U+IQ6aUNk=",
            "email": "t@tt.tt",
            "date_joined": "2012-06-11T06:44:57.637Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "test_app.userprofile",
        "fields": {
            "language": "example.com",
            "user": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Also, here's another possibility to make a UserProfile class, with [django-annoying](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home):

```
from annoying.fields import AutoOneToOneField


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField('auth.User', primary_key=True)
    home_page = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Also, it's NOT one to one rel because user can have many profiles. :)

Comment: A User can only have one profile, because UserProfile.user is unique !

Comment: Just to clarify this statement: "Absolutely, if a fixture has a pk which exists in the database, django will do an update"

For clarity, I'd add *so long as you specify the fields*. If you don't, django will clear them out.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the raw parameter in create profile. It indicates, if it comes from a fixture or not, check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) for more details. This way you can control the creation of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to also take a look at [django-pyfixture](https://django-pyfixture.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). That would make your data look like fixture, but be a bit more "smart".